# How do I display the usage flags for my encryption keys in a less hackish way?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, permissions

I am trying to educate myself on the use of encryption keys and I've been experimenting with this old Linus Torvalds’ key that I found `956EB7BF449FA3AB`.

I am interested to display the usage flags but neither `gpg2 --list-keys 449FA3AB` nor `gpg2 --fingerprint  449FA3AB` display the usage flags.

The only way I've found to get the usage flag information is this hackish way.

```
$ gpg2 --edit-key 449FA3AB
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.26; Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.


pub  1024D/449FA3AB  created: 1999-10-05  expired: 2001-10-04  usage: SCA 
                     trust: unknown       validity: expired
sub  2048g/BFF491C5  created: 1999-10-05  expired: 2001-10-04  usage: E   
[ expired] (1). Linus Torvalds <torvalds@transmeta.com>

gpg> quit

$
```

What is the official way to display the usage flags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The machine-readable format using `--with-colons` contains the usage flag as last column. It is not very readable for humans, but contains the data you're looking for.

```
$ gpg2 --with-colons --list-keys 449FA3AB
tru::1:1414619239:1414879758:3:1:5
pub:e:1024:17:956EB7BF449FA3AB:939086351:1002158351::-:::sca:
uid:e::::939086351::81A3799583B9B1B391E4C428112F302FF2ADF462::Linus Torvalds <torvalds@transmeta.com>:
sub:e:2048:16:71CE8207BFF491C5:939086545:1002158545:::::e:
```

Torwald's public key can be used for signing, certifications and authentication; the subkey can be used for encryption.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Seems like this Torvalds-key has some special feature that hides the sub-key (i.e. when running `gpg2 --list-keys 449FA3AB`). However, the sub-key does show when running `gpg2 --with-colons --list-keys 449FA3AB`. What you say about separating the different key-features, with separate expiration dates, also makes good sense (However, I am still struggling to understand why I want a public key for _signing_, _certifying other signatures_, and for _authentication_, but that's focus of another this question, hence the parenthesis).

Comment: As this actually puzzled me for a minute or two, I wrote up the answer in some Q&A: http://superuser.com/q/835691/102155.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that later versions of GnuPG (2.1+?) have a parameter value for `--list-options` that will do this:

```
$ gpg --list-options show-usage --list-keys
```

Like any of the long options this can be persisted in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`:

```
list-options show-usage
```