# Why is gpg --list-keys sometimes printing subkeys, sometimes not?

Tags: gnupg, openpgp

*This question occured in the comments of "[How do I display the usage flags for my encryption keys in a less hackish way?](https://superuser.com/q/833875/102155)", and seems worth being answered in a Q&A form as the answer is not actually obvious.*

To view Torvald's OpenPGP key 449FA3AB, I use `gpg2 --list-keys 449FA3AB`, which outputs

```
$ gpg2 --list-keys 449FA3AB
pub   1024D/449FA3AB 1999-10-05 [expired: 2001-10-04]
uid       [ expired] Linus Torvalds <torvalds@transmeta.com>
```

Usually, this command also lists subkeys, but no subkeys are printed for Torvald's key. Yet, when requesting batch output, there is one included.

```
$ gpg2 --with-colons --list-keys 449FA3AB
tru::1:1414619239:1414879758:3:1:5
pub:e:1024:17:956EB7BF449FA3AB:939086351:1002158351::-:::sca:
uid:e::::939086351::81A3799583B9B1B391E4C428112F302FF2ADF462::Linus Torvalds <torvalds@transmeta.com>:
sub:e:2048:16:71CE8207BFF491C5:939086545:1002158545:::::e:
```

Seems like this Torvalds-key has some special feature that hides the sub-key. What happened here?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Expired Keys

This is no special feature, but Torvalds primary key is expired quite some time ago, and in consequence also the subkey. The answer is hidden in GnuPG's `--list-options` section of the man pages, as by default expired subkeys are hidden. From `man gpg2`:

```
show-unusable-subkeys
        Show revoked and expired subkeys in key listings. Defaults to no.
```

By specifying this argument, the subkey will show up:

```
$ gpg2 --list-options show-unusable-subkeys --list-keys 449FA3AB
pub   1024D/449FA3AB 1999-10-05 [expired: 2001-10-04]
uid       [ expired] Linus Torvalds <torvalds@transmeta.com>
sub   2048g/BFF491C5 1999-10-05 [expired: 2001-10-04]
```

### Travelling Back in Time

You can also verify this using the helpful [`faketime`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/faketime.1.html) program to set the system time back some years for GnuPG. By travelling back in time to some date where Torvalds key was valid, the subkey will show up again:

```
$ faketime 2001-01-01 gpg2 --list-keys 449FA3AB
pub   1024D/449FA3AB 1999-10-05 [expires: 2001-10-04]
uid       [ unknown] Linus Torvalds <torvalds@transmeta.com>
sub   2048g/BFF491C5 1999-10-05 [expires: 2001-10-04]
```

Comment: It appears that the lowercase flags on the primary key in the `--with-colons` output (and some other places) may offer a clue about the expiration—I've only found documentation of it in library docs like [this Perl lib](http://fossies.org/linux/GnuPG-Interface/lib/GnuPG/Key.pm) so far (search `usage_flags`), but uppercase seems to indicate *usable* capabilities, i.e. not conveyed by expired or revoked keys.

Comment: The documentation you're looking for is stored in `/usr/share/doc/gnupg/DETAILS.gz` (path might be different for different distributions) and also available [in the GnuPG git repository](http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/DETAILS). Check out "Field 12 - Key capabilities".